# !eeheap -gc showing only 1 GC heap although my process is running on quad-core processor machine

Tags: .net, windbg, sos

My .net based application is running on a quad-core machine but when I run !eeheap -gc command it shows

> Number of GC Heaps: 1

Does it mean my application is not using all 4 processors? Any idea why this may be happening and how this behaviour can be changed?

Comment: Why do you expect one GC heap per processor? Memory is shared between processors, so it doesn't make sense to have one heap per processor.

Comment: @svick: Google about difference between server and workstation modes of GC. You will get the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to enable Server GC  to have multiple heaps

[gcServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229357.aspx)

```
<Configuration>
    <runtime>
        <gcServer enabled=“true“ />
    </runtime>
</Configuration>
```